# What does "weight" on search results in PyPI help in choosing a package?

Tags: python, pypi

When I search "XML parse" in [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org), the matched results are listed according to "weight". When I hove my  mouse over "weight", it says "occurrence of search term weighted by field (name, summary, keywords, description, author, maintainer)".

- What does "weighted by field (name, summary, keywords, description, author, maintainer)" mean?
- Ideally, does a package ranked higher most likely better than a package ranked lower?

Thanks.

Comment: it is about how i pick a package from PyPI.

Answer (score 5):

Interesting question! I cloned the [pypi repository](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/pypi) and searched for "weight", which gave me this line:

```
./templates/index.pt:15: <th tal:condition="exists:data/scores"><u title="Occurrence of search term weighted by field (name, summary, keywords, description, author, maintainer)">Weight*</u></th>
```

Then based on that I searched for "scores", which led me to the [`search`](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/pypi/src/b7fa64647a19d08147110c0c444a4af4ac458cda/webui.py?at=default#cl-1789) function. In that function, it defines the weight given to the different columns:

```
    columns = [
        ('name', 4),      # doubled for exact (case-insensitive) match
        ('summary', 2),
        ('keywords', 2),
        ('description', 1),
        ('author', 1),
        ('maintainer', 1),
    ]
```

So if your search term appears in the package's name it gets a score of 4, if it appears in the summary it gets a score of 2, and so on. It calculates this for each term then adds them all up.

In your example, for "XML parse", the top package is [Products.ParsedXML](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Products.ParsedXML/1.5.1). The score is calculated something like this:

- Name: "Products.ParsedXML" = 4 + 4 = **8**
- Summary: "Parsed XML allows you..." = 2 + 2 = **4**
- Keywords: "parsedxml xml zope2" = 2 + 2 = **4**
- Description: "Parsed XML allows you to..." = 1 + 1 = **2**
- Author: "Zope community, and various others contributors" = **0**
- Maintainer: (empty) = **0**
- **Total = 8 + 4 + 4 + 2 + 0 + 0 = 18**

And **18** is indeed the score on the search result page.

So, to get the best possible score you would need to have every field match the desired search terms (AKA "[keyword stuffing](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66358?hl=en)"). If you're thinking of publishing a package I don't recommend you try to game the system though. The algorithm for scoring is simple because it's relying on people to be honest. If everyone tried to stuff extra keywords into these fields to get a higher score it would be a mess and in the end give worse search results.

Comment: Thanks. Is there quality and user ratings or something similar of packages, so that it can help me to choose which one out of similar ones?

Comment: No, pypi doesn't have ratings of user packages. Pypi shows you the download count, and there are some sites that let you look at download counts to see how popular a package is: http://pypi-ranking.info/alltime Other than that I would look at: how many stars/followers it has on github/bitbucket, how good is the documentation, does it have tests, does it have active developers, does it have a current release, etc.. Then experiment with the package to see how well it works.

Answer (score -2):

```
jobskills = {'java': 10, 'python': 20, 'jquery': 5}

candidateskills = ['python', 'java','angular']

foundskills={k:jobskills[k] for k in candidateskills if k in jobskills}

print sum(foundskills.values())
```